# Debugging an application in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I may sound silly, but I am naive in debugging.
I have one doubt, in order to track the flow of execution in a program, what should be the optimum point to put a breakpoint?
Is it so that wherever we will put a breakpoint, the application execution flow before that would not be traced?

Comment: Tracing has nothing to do with it, not is there any "performance" consideration while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best point to place a breakpoint is where you need the function to break.

If that exact point will not be reached because of conditionals, break on the conditional that would cause it to skip and ensure the code you *do* want to debug will get reached.

You need to place breakpoints where you can get to the code you wish to debug the fastest.

Comment: Thank you so much for the early response. I am clear with the doubt.I have one more doubt, should I use F10 or F11?

Comment: @ItiTyagi - If you need to go into the functions being called, use `F11`, otherwise, `F10`. What you should do, is try both till you understand how each works. There is no "right" way to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You would place a breakpoint very near or just before a piece of code you want to step through in order to debug it, then when execution pauses at your breakpoint, step through line by line to examine the state of variables and follow the path of execution.